# Mongodb Mongoose Schema.Types.Mixed Text Search

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

good day all,

need some help figuring out mongodb, mongoose and text search.

i have this as a schema

```
var itemSchema = new schema({
  itemID: Number,
  description: {type: Schema.Types.Mixed}
}
```

and in the collection in mongodb i have something like this

```
[
 {
    itemID:1
    description: {
        en: "car string in itemid 1"
        fr: "voiture string in itemid 1"
        es: "spanish string in itemid 1"
    }
 },
 {
    itemID:2
    description: {
        en: "motorcycle string in itemid 2"
        fr: "motocyclette string in itemid 2"
        es: "spanish string in itemid 2"
    }
 }
]
```

how do i do a text search like let's say i'm looking for "voiture" in description.

is the Schema.Types.Mixed appropriate for this kind of search or should it be changed. and how should i index such a field for better performance

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can only have [one text index per collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/), so rather than have an object with properties as strings I would suggest an array of objects that have the text and the language:

```
description: [
  { lang: "en", text: "car string in itemid 1" }
]
```

Then you could create an index like `createIndex({ "description.lang": 1, "description.text": "text" })`. Then query like `query({ "description.lang": "fr", { $text: {$search: "voiture" } })`. This assumes the language is known ahead of time which would be a more efficient query, but you could also create the index without the lang in which case all of the `"description.text"` properties would be searched.

Comment: thank you for the quick answer. i will apply your suggestion.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it does not work., when i do a query, it just retunr the cursor with no message like nothig was found or nothing was done at all.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it does not work, when i do a query, it just return the cursor with no message like nothing was found or nothing was done at all. When i do an explain on it i see all the query params are there, it is doing an index scan on the text index but still not return ing anything. i can manually check that the word i'm looking for is actually in the collection field. So the question is can Mongodb do a text search on an array of Objects or does it need to be structured some other way for it to work.

Comment: It needs to be structured the way I had it in my answer

Comment: i did and this is the parse query   from the explain statement 
  "parsedQuery" : { "$and" : [ { "description.lang" : {      "$eq" : "fr"
                        }
                },
                {
                        "$text" : {
                                "$search" : "haut",
                                "$language" : "english",
                                "$caseSensitive" : false,
                                "$diacriticSensitive" : false
                        }
                }
        ]
},